# Splitting string by spaces (java)

Tags: java

i'm trying to read in student information in one line, the line contains ID, name, age and gpa. I want to split the line by spaces and store each token in my string array Splited[]. Why does this code give me ArrayOutOfBounds error on the line `String name = splited[1];` ?
Sample input: `3844 Jim 30 3.4` 
thank you

```
       String [] splited = new String [4];

       System.out.println("Enter student Id, name, age and gpa: ");
       String info = keyboard.next();
       //separate student info line by spaces
          splited = info.split("\\s");

       int id = Integer.parseInt(splited[0]);
       String name = splited[1];
       int age = Integer.parseInt(splited[2]);
       double gpa = Double.parseDouble(splited[3]);
```

Comment: Have you tried with split(" ") ?

Comment: @Blueriver yes i still get the same error

Comment: Show as a sample input

Comment: Note that `new String[4]` is useless.  This creates a new array with four elements (all `null`), and you assign `splited` to it--`splited` is actually a reference to the array object.  But then, when you assign `splited` to the result of `split()`, you're assigning it to a reference to a different array, and the four-element array becomes garbage.  Creating the 4-element array has no effect on `split`, which never sees the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String info = keyboard.next();` is returning the first `String` separated by a white space (so that would be `id`) in your case.

Try using `String info = keyboard.nextLine();` which will return the entire content up to the new line character.  Then you can use `String#split` (or another `Scanner`) to parse the text

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use " " instead of "\s" to split the input. and you should check the validity of the input.

actual problem is: keyboard.next() only reads the next word (space is a defaultdelimiter of the scanner). use keyboard.nextLine() instead.

Comment: sry, i just noticed something: the actual problem is somewhere else: keyboard.next() only reads the next word (space is a defaultdelimiter of the scanner). use keyboard.nextLine() instead.

Comment: that solved the problem! Thank you, i will choose your answer as the correct one if you make the necessary edits.